# Create a sequence of multi-dimensional (2X2) arrays in python

Tags: python, numpy

I want to be able to create a sequence of 2x2 arrays that when I try to print a specific index it prints a 2x2 array.

```
H = np.array(Ez_centre[0]*I_z)
for i in range(1,img.shape[0]):
    H = np.append(H,np.array(Ez_centre[i]*I_z),axis=1)
```

This just creates one big array

Comment: Instead of asking about a specific mechanism, why not start with what problem you're trying to solve that makes you think you need that mechanism?  A numpy ndarray might or might not be appropriate...

Comment: do not use `np.append`.  List append is faster, and easier to get right.

Comment: what's `Ez_centre`?  list, array?  `Ez_centre[i]`

Comment: What about `H=[Ez_centre[i]*I_z for i in range(...)]`?

Answer (score 2):

as Mark Reed mentioned
providing a bit of context would be very helpful but if you just want to know how to create sequences of array, one answer could be:

```
Create an array of N elements and then reshape it into the form you wanted.

np.arange(0,16)
#output =  array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15])

# reshape it 
output.reshape(4,2,2) # (number of batches, number of row , number of columns)


# array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 2,  3]],

       [[ 4,  5],
        [ 6,  7]],

       [[ 8,  9],
        [10, 11]],

       [[12, 13],
        [14, 15]]])
```